# In Pandemic, can the Coordinator's ability be used on another player's turn?

Tags: pandemic

In Pandemic, one of the role is "coordinator" aka "dispatcher".

The rules say:

- Move your fellow players' pawns on your turn as if they were your own.
- Move any pawn to another city containing a pawn for 1 action.

It is not clear if the coordinator can move the pawn at any time or only during their turn.

Answer (score 6):

Only on your turn.

**If you're asking about the first ability**

All the first ability does is allow you to treat all pawns as your own when you take a move action.

You can only move your own pawns on your turn, so you can only move their pawns on your turn. The same action cost that would apply to moving your own pawns applies when moving their pawns.

**If you're asking about the second ability**

You may only take actions on your turn. You have no action points to spend outside of your turn.

Comment: Why does it say "on your turn" only for the first move? It seems to me that it can move the pawn to a city containing another pawn at amy time.

Comment: Because people find it confusing otherwise. I thought you did too, but it now appears you're asking about the second ability? Adjusted my answer.

Comment: Ok. Even though, it could be that the coordinator uses the action of the pawn to move: at the turn of player X, the coordinator moves X's pawn using one action.

Comment: Or at the turn of X, the coordinator moves Y's pawn using X's action.

Comment: Re "*it could be that the coordinator uses the action of the pawn to move: at the turn of player X, the coordinator moves X's pawn using one action*", No, it couldn't be. As the answer already explains, you have no actions to spend on another player's turn.

Comment: Re "*Or at the turn of X, the coordinator moves Y's pawn using X's action.*", No, nothing about the dispatcher's ability suggest that other players can use the dispatcher's ability on their turn. Just like the dispatcher can't use the Medic's ability.